# left join without explicit relationship in nhibernate 3.3.1.4000

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have these two simplified entities:

```
public class Measurement : Entity
{
    public virtual float DisplayValue { get; set; }
    private DateTime _timeStamp;
    public virtual DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get { return _timeStamp; }
        set { _timeStamp = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
    }
}

public class TimeStamp : Entity
{
    public virtual DateTime TimeStampEntry { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using this (my)sql code to determine missing values over a range:

```
SET time_zone='+0:00';  
select 
    a.TimeStampEntry,
    b.DisplayValue
from timestamps as a 
left outer join  
(
    select
        TimeStamp,
        DisplayValue
    from measurements 
) as b on a.TimeStampEntry = b.TimeStamp
where a.TimeStampEntry>='2010-01-01 00:00:00' and a.TimeStampEntry<'2010-01-31 23:59:59' and b.DisplayValue is null
order by a.TimeStampEntry asc
```

I am just wondering how I could achieve this in Nhibernate 3.x, preferably in Linq.

BTW, I have not tried anything serious as the relationship between the datetime fields is not defined in fluent nhibernate. Not sure whether I have to define this to be able to use ICriteria, Linq, HQL or whatever. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

PS:

I have made a start with this (not working code):

```
var x = (from ts in NHibernateSession.Current.Query<TimeStamp>()
                         join m in NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Measurement>()
                         on ts.TimeStampEntry equals m.TimeStamp into ps
                         from m in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { m.TimeStamp }).ToList();
```

PPS:

stacktrace:

```
at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitGroupJoinClause(GroupJoinClause groupJoinClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.GroupJoinClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: What isn't working about that code?

Comment: Exception: The method or operation is not implemented. I read that linq to nhibernate does not support left joins. Not sure whether this has changed. I am using NH 3.3.1.4000

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't really need a left join – you're only using the right table in aggregate. This is a good place for a simpler (in LINQ) group join:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.new(year, month, 1);
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(1);

var x =
    from ts in NHibernateSession.Current.Query<TimeStamp>()
    join m in NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Measurement>()
        on ts.TimeStampEntry equals m.TimeStamp
        into ps
    where
        ts.TimeStampEntry >= start &&
        ts.TimeStampEntry < end &&
        ! ps.Any()
    orderby ts.TimeStampEntry
    select ts.TimeStampEntry;
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same exception!

Comment: Does it tell you which method is not implemented?

Comment: Thom can you please have a look into this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know enough about nHibernate to figure out from the data provided which method is unsupported.